# How to counter jets from little bird

Tags: battlefield-4

Lately I'm playing on Silk Road often, with 2-3 friends.
We often play as Little-Bird squad and perform well in general.

A Little bird (Headseeker, 30mm, flares or ECM) with 2 repairman( RPG-7, repair-tool / Stinger, repair-tool)

However, when it comes to JET pilots which are at least a little above average on skill, we fail all the times.

If the jet has used flares and is in range, we instantly get him down (2 headseaker + 1 stinger).

What strategies can we use to get them jets down, when jet uses hit and run tactic, most times with flares not ECM?
Sometimes we have a engineer-player inside a Tank or LAV on the ground to (RPG / Repair-Tool), if this could become a factor.
Stressing the jet with LMG from vehicle isn't much of a help, due we have to be nearby the vehicle all the time, which would lower our effectiveness.

We've tried a lot, best strategies until now is the following:
Engie on the ground uses SOFLAM as secondary weapon on gunner slot.
He can provoke the jets to flare, sometimes but not very often.

But this has big problems:

- We have to stay relatively close to ground personal
- Ground personal could be in a separate fight which we could not end fast. Any inf coming toward our ground personal isn't a problem due we kill it fast, but tanks take time.
- Jets still can escape
- Ground personal takes some time to switch slot
- Ground personal is completely immobile and relatively vulnerable while using SOFLAM

Comment: Do you want to defend from Jets, or do you want to hunt them, sacrificing Anti-armor capabilities?

Comment: Defense. AP capability has to stay up.

Comment: Most jet pilots leave their jet, if we deal much damage in short time, even if engine is ok and (from our perspective) kill potential isn't there.
Most pilots leave after, lets say 15-30 dmg from railgun + one heatseeker.
Problem is, how to hit with heatseekers, if they flare so quickly.
Even if we wait to shoot the heatseekers until the jet almost reached our position, the pilot has time to flare.
Sometimes, we can manage to provoke flares by locking and shooting at max range, then waiting for lockability, lock, shot. but this is luck., most times they abort their attack after flares.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch 25mm cannons to 7.62, they are more accurate and can damage jet more.
2. Move! Don't let Jet line up with you. Change altitude and direction when you see attacking jet. Use terrain to hide from Jet.
3. Use you base automated AA-turret. Spotted aircraft automaticaly targetter by it. If you can't deal with Jet yourself, retreat to base.
4. Igla launcher will give engineer more range than Stinger: 450m vs 350m.

Since you have SOFLAM, you also can try to use Laser-Guided Helicopter missiles. They can be launched on laser-designated jet. Try it.

Equip pilot as Support with Ammo squad upgrades. With 4 level squad perk it will resupply onboard engineers with rockets.

Comment: 1. 7.62 is not an option on Silkroad, due it doesn't penetrate mbts and lavs. 
2. Maneuvering to avoid jets is the cheapest und most effective way to avoid getting killed, sure, we already do this. Hiding behind hills and stuff is impossible on this map, it's pretty plain.
3. You mean the heatseeker? Jet uses flares, gg.
4. We'll pack Igla next time, we'll see how it improves the situation.
5. Laser guidet: Can these be blocked with ECM or Flares? Can they hit tanks as well, if laser locked?

Comment: 3. No, Base AA is stationary unmaned 20mm gun platform. It automatically fire at any enemy _spotted_ aircraft flying over your base. 4. Igla requires holding lock to hit target, so it is harder to use from passenger seat, you need to coordinate actions with your passengers. However this also allow to reaquire lock after flares. 5. Soflam targetting and guided missile both will be blocked by flares and ECM. Laser Guided missile will hit tank for 30 damage with direct attack and 50 damage on laser guide.

Comment: Tried igla for a couple of matches, doesn't fit. While holding lock up, we cant repair.

Comment: Anyway, it can be used to force enemy to use flares from greater distance, allowing you to launch both missiles at same time.

Comment: For now it seems, like SOFLAM support is best we can get.
With its 500m locking range, SOFLAM is a pretty awesome support.

Comment: Then you can switch onboard engineer to Javelin. It hits 90% vs air and 45% vs armor on laser lock.